# How to `watch` output of `xxd` or `hexdump` command?

Tags: pipe, watch, hexdump, xxd

My tool is wtiting binary chars to `stdout` and I can view it in hex with

```
# ./md /dev/ttyUSB0 | xxd
0000000: 6f03 1100 0003 0084 8400 0000 0900 0a00  o...............
0000010: 0008 0004 0000 0000 2c00 0000 0000 0000  ........,.......
...
00000b0: 8000 8000 8000 8000 8000 8000 8000 8000  ................
00000c0: 8047 ffff ff6f 04fd 2180 ff02 f700 f702  .G...o..!.......
00000d0: fbb6 00bf 10e1 a57f 4004 fb00 a780 7e00  ........@.
```

unfortunately, when I am trying to `watch` this screen

```
watch `./md /dev/ttyUSB0 | xxd`

watch `./md /dev/ttyUSB0 | hexdump`
```

It prints something like

[image]

either corrupting or misinterpretting output.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bacticks are used for command substitution, you need:

```
watch './md /dev/ttyUSB0 | xxd'
```

Comment: aaaaaaaaa! thanks!